# How to make custom circle in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I got a project from a client and the UI looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/os55q.png)

I have a problem creating the gradient circle background. My code looks like this:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: gradient,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                bottomLeft: const Radius.circular(1500.0),
                bottomRight: const Radius.circular(1500.0),
              ),
            ),
            height: 450,
            child: Center(
              child: Container(
                width: 195,
                height: 195,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                ),
                child: Image.asset(
                  'assets/logo_new.png',
                  width: 200,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container()
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

and it looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgFxy.png)

Can anyone help me creating the circle gradient background and positioning the white circle on the bottom of it

ps: This is my first time asking in StackOverflow, so I'm sorry if my question doesn't make sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rather go with a `Positioned` widget inside a `Stack` and use `MediaQuery.of(context).size` to calculate position and size of you gradient box based on phone screen size. The following will draw a big circle that is partly outside the screen. You can adjust the formulas to fine tune.

Note: this will do what you need in portait, in landscape it will be different. If you need different, either find out how to create formulas with `MediaQuery` to match landscape as well, or check out [OrientationBuilder](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/orientation) widget and use different versions in portrait and landscape.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Stack(
      children: [
        Positioned(
            left: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width -
                    MediaQuery.of(context).size.height) /
                2,
            top: -1 * MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
            child: Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                gradient: gradient,
              ),
            )),
        Center(
          child: Container(
            width: 195,
            height: 195,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
            ),
            child: Image.asset(
                'assets/logo_new.png',
                 width: 200,
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help! it works even though it looks a bit different, but no problem I believe.

Comment: You can play width the sizes, make the circle a little bigger etc. If you find my answer useful please upvote / mark as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

use `stack` widget

```
Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 550,
            child: Stack(
              alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomCenter,
              children: [
                Positioned( // <-- blue container
                  top: 0,
                  child: Container(
                    height: 450,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      gradient: new LinearGradient(
                          colors: [
                            const Color(0xFF3366FF),
                            const Color(0xFF00CCFF),
                          ],
                          begin: const FractionalOffset(0.0, 0.0),
                          end: const FractionalOffset(1.0, 0.0),
                          stops: [0.0, 1.0],
                          tileMode: TileMode.clamp),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        bottomLeft: const Radius.circular(1500.0),
                        bottomRight: const Radius.circular(1500.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(//<-- image container
                  bottom: 0,
                  child: Container(
                    width: 200,
                    height: 200,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    ),
                    child: Container(
                      width: 195,
                      height: 195,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.yellow,
                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      ),
                      child: Image.asset(
                        MyResources.cameraPng, //<-- image path
                        width: 200,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(// <-- text
                  top: 150,
                  child: Text(
                    'HELLO   !',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 55, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container( //<-- button is here
            width: 300,
            height: 50,
            color: Colors.red,
            child: Center(
              child: Text('your button',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white)),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! although the circle I want to create looks a bit different, I still using this.